# Office 365 - Word developer mode: yes! But no

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

In Microsoft's Word (in this case from the Office 365 package), developer's mode solves a lot of impracticalities and may help in document consistency.

I just discovered it's possible to use the "repeating sections" function to duplicate, for instance, new sections or chapters.

In this case, I have a set of three things I want to repeat every time I start a new chapter:

- Heading 1 with text field, hard enter
- Text field, hard enter
- Section ending (new section on uneven page)

So, I try to bundle these in one repeating section. It works! Great!

However, naturally and logically, when the text fields are altered in this chapter, and thén the "+" of the repeating sections is clicked, you get what you asked for: a duplicate. So with the exact same text; not a blank new chapter.

Is there a possibility to have a blank set of fields repeated, with the repetitions being blank, i.e. independent of what changed to the text fields within that section?

No big deal if it isn't possible (then I could just add a second 'trinity' just for this purpose and leave that one blank until the document is finished), but since I'm discovering new quality-of-life features in Word, I thought I'd give this question a go.

--

ADDENDUM
I just found out it is possible to do so with the 'modern' text fields.

Answer (score -1):

### You could save your content-free repeating section as AutoText or a Quick Part.

Here is a [Microsoft page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-reusable-text-snippets-0bc40cab-f49c-4e06-bcb2-cd43c1674d1b) on this. Here is [my page](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoComplete).